# When I try to run app I get this error. Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to compile code in Android Studio and getting this error.

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: C:\Users\Anonymous\OneDrive\Projects\usama_khalid\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\usama_khalid\usama_khalid\MainActivity.kt: (3, 19): Unresolved reference: embedding
e: C:\Users\Anonymous\OneDrive\Projects\usama_khalid\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\usama_khalid\usama_khalid\MainActivity.kt: (5, 21): Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: C:\Users\Anonymous\OneDrive\Projects\usama_khalid\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\usama_khalid\usama_khalid\MainActivity.kt: (3, 19): Unresolved reference: embedding
e: C:\Users\Anonymous\OneDrive\Projects\usama_khalid\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\usama_khalid\usama_khalid\MainActivity.kt: (5, 21): Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 4s

- List item

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKbXe.png)

Comment: please add the code snippet for more understanding which is producing this error

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Text("Hello World"),
    ),
  );
}

Comment: bad format...........................................